Upgrading to 24.04 LTS broke calendar notifications
I have a dual boot PC. I haven't used Ubuntu for over a year due to some software that made dual-boot impractical. I moved that software to my Raspberry Pi 5, so now dual-boot is back in business.
I was getting reliable notifications from Calendar under 22.04 but after upgrading to 24.04, I no longer get the popups.
The following notifications are enabled for Calendar under settings:

notifications
sound alerts
notification popups
lock screen notifications

I have a preexisting recurring daily appointment. I do get notifications for this appointment but no popup - actually I get the popup only after I click on the notification. I don't even get notifications for new appointments let alone popups.
Any idea how I fix this. Alternately is there a calendar app for Ubuntu that will reliably give me popup notifications with sound.
Ironically, one of the main reasons I was keen to get back on to Ubuntu was the new Outlook where notifications are unreliable. I am currently using the old Outlook on Windows 11 but am afraid that Microsoft will force me to use the new buggy one at some stage.

I've had the same issue.
In order to revert to the old behavior I ran the following command:
gsettings set org.gnome.evolution-data-server.calendar notify-with-tray false

The description of this setting being:
Show reminders in notification tray only


Thanks mate. Now I get popups for the preexisting daily appointment - no audio signal unfortunately. I still get no notifications for any new events that I enter.

The Calendar App is not saving the reminders. Using evolution I now get the popup reminders. No audio unfortunately.

@rusty Can confirm Gnome Calendar does not save reminders on 24.04.1.
